# How to annotate on a single object and not a QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django

When annotating something to a model in Django one would write something like this:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(total_yes_votes=Count('vote', filter=Q(vote__vote_choice='yes')))
```

What if I want to annotate on a single object and not all() the objects:

```
Post.objects.get(id=id).annotate(total_yes_votes=Count('vote', filter=Q(vote__vote_choice='yes')))
```

By the way, it doesn't work.

Isn't it more efficient to annotate a single object rather than all()?

Answer (score 2):

Move the call to `.get()` to after the annotation

```
Post.objects.annotate(total_yes_votes=Count('vote', filter=Q(vote__vote_choice='yes'))).get(id=id)
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Post' object has not attribute annotate`

Comment: @Steffi: That sounds like you're trying to do `some_post.annotate`, but you need to use `.annotate` on `Post.objects`, i.e. before the `.get`, not after.